# xdg-open equivalent for opening file manager for all variants?

Tags: filemanager

I'm looking for the equivalent of this command:

```
xdg-open /home/file.txt
```

Not to open gedit, leafpad or kate, but to open a file manager, like nautilus, thunar or dolphin.

Is a such command exist ?
Thanks

Comment: So you want it to open a file manager instead of the default program for the application when using `xdg-open` - why not use `nautilus /home/file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but you can tell it to open the directory containing the file:

```
xdg-open $(dirname /home/file.txt)
```

Be warned that this may have unexpected results on occasion. After I installed [links](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/links.1.html), this started opening `links` instead of `nautilus`.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu and the command has opened Kate, as I would like. I will try to code with this.

Comment: @Guillaume It opened Kate? I thought that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: Oh sorry, I would like to say "Dolphin" !!

Answer (score 0):

use gdbus this also allows to open the file manager even if filepath or filename contains comma doesnt work in dbus-send

ex:

```
FILE="path to file/file" #contains comma

gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.FileManager1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 --method org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems "['file://$FILE']" ""
```